# image not display using Picasso Library in Listview ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am using this ArrayAdapter class to show image in Listview. but it barely display 1 or 2 images, and can work fast and show Image. Also when i scroll it up-down then image get disappear.

```
@SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
public class New_Contest_ArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
  private final Context context;
  private final String[] contest_names;
  private final String[] contest_start_dates;
  private final String[] contest_end_dates;
  private final String[] contest_pic_path;
  int selected_pos=0;

  public New_Contest_ArrayAdapter(Context context, int pos,String[] values,String[] values1,String[]values2,String[]pic_path) 
  {
    super(context, pos, values);
    this.context = context;
    this.contest_names = values;
    this.selected_pos=pos;
    this.contest_start_dates=values1;
    this.contest_end_dates=values2;
    this.contest_pic_path=pic_path;
  }

  static class ViewHolder 
    { 
         public ImageView imgvw;
         public TextView namesTV,datesTV,livestatusTV;
         Button viewBTN,deleteBTN;


         }


  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
  {
      ViewHolder holder;
      View   rowView = null ;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (rowView == null) 
    {
         holder = new ViewHolder();
   // rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_contest_adapter,null);
         rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_contest_adapter, parent, false);    

    holder.namesTV = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
     holder.datesTV = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    holder.livestatusTV = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    holder.imgvw=(ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    rowView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
         holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
     }


   holder.namesTV.setText(""+contest_names[position]);
    holder.datesTV.setText("Started On: "+contest_start_dates[position]);
   holder.livestatusTV.setText("End On:     "+contest_end_dates[position]);

    if(contest_pic_path[position].length()>5)
    {
       setImagesUsingPicasso(contest_pic_path[position],holder.imgvw);
    //  Picasso.with(context).load(contest_pic_path[position]).fit().centerCrop().into(imgvw);
    }
    else
        holder.imgvw.setImageResource(R.drawable.contest_icon);

 return rowView;

  }

  //(((((( Loading Profile Pic with PICASSO Library ))))))))
  private void setImagesUsingPicasso(String imagePath,final ImageView profileIV) 
    {

          String url="http://pir.alphasols.com/VotingAppFolder/ContestProfilePicFolder/"+imagePath;

         // Toast.makeText(getContext(), ""+url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          Log.e("url- ",""+url);

        Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(new Target()
        {

            public void onBitmapLoaded ( Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from)
            {
               // theView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);               

                //bitmap=getRoundedRectBitmap(bitmap, 100);
                profileIV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


            }

            @Override
            public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable arg0)
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
    });
     }      

//((( Make Round Cirle IMAGEVIEW ))))
    public static Bitmap getRoundedRectBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int radius) 
    {

        Bitmap finalBitmap;
        if (bitmap.getWidth() != radius || bitmap.getHeight() != radius)
               finalBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, radius, radius,
                            false);
        else
               finalBitmap = bitmap;
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(finalBitmap.getWidth(),
                     finalBitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, finalBitmap.getWidth(),
                     finalBitmap.getHeight());

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399"));
        canvas.drawCircle(finalBitmap.getWidth() / 2 + 0.7f,
                     finalBitmap.getHeight() / 2 + 0.7f,
                     finalBitmap.getWidth() / 2 + 0.1f, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(finalBitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;


    }



} //EOF Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the (much simpler) call `Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(profileIV);` working? Are you sure the url is correct?

BTW: `View rowView = null ;` should be `View rowView = convertView ;` I guess, and you can move the `getSystemService()` call inside the if-statement.

Comment: Let me change the code to yours, and then telling you

Comment: Soory i change the code, now it is mixing all the picture

Comment: Please try setting the `R.drawable.contest_icon` with Picasso, too.

Comment: Edit: Do you mean the pictures are appearing on wrong positions in your list?
Use the `error` method for Picasso to set a default image (contest_icon ?) if an error occured. And please try setting the `R.drawable.contest_icon` with Picasso, too.

Comment: Yes it is showing at wrong postion, one picture at different place

Comment: What's the `contest_pic_path[position].length()>5` about?

Make sure you are either setting an image or clearing the content of your imageview on each `getView()` call. Since views are being recycled, it's possible that the `convertView`  already shows an image when it's being passed to the `getView()` method.

Comment: contest_pic_path is picture array names , like image.jpg, later on i am mixing with url below in this class